# react-map-js popup won't close / remove

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gis, deck.gl, react-map-gl

I successfully added a popup on my map, but I can't figure out how to close the popup. (I think it's a bug?)

I imported the Popup;

```
import MapGL, { Popup } from 'react-map-gl';
```

and defined the popup method like the following;

```
_renderPopup() {
  return(
    <Popup
      anchor="bottom"
      tipSize={10}
      longitude={this.state.popupInfo.lon}
      latitude={this.state.popupInfo.lat}
      closeButton={true}
      closeOnClick={true}
      >
        <div style={style_popup}>
          <p> lon = {this.state.popupInfo.lon} </p>
          <p> lat = {this.state.popupInfo.lat} </p>
        </div>
    </Popup>
  );
}
```

which I rendered like this;

```
render() {
  const {viewport, data, popupInfo} = this.state;
    return (
      <MapGL
        {...viewport}
        {...this.props}
        onViewportChange={this._onViewportChange.bind(this)}
        mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_TOKEN}
        mapStyle={MAP_STYLE}
      >
        {this._renderPopup()}
      </MapGL>
    );
  }
}
```

It renders properly and the close button is on the popup. It just won't close.
Any ideas? :/

Answer (score 0):

Per the most recent [documentation of Popup component](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/docs/api-reference/popup) from `react-map-gl`,

you could set up a hook for closing the window

```
const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(true)
```

and then call it in the onClose event

```
<Popup
  longitude={-100}
  latitude={40}
  anchor="bottom"
  onClose={() => setShowPopup(false)}>
  You are here
</Popup>)
```